# Java event handlers

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I am writing a small Java app (on Windows, hence the _on_vista appended to my name).

I got 3 buttons, all of which will react to a click event, but do different things.

Is the following code the accepted way or is there a cleaner way I do not know about?
On one half, it works, on the other half, something doesn't seem right...

Thanks

```
cool_button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        coolfunction1();
    }
});

cool_button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        coolfunction2();
    }
});

// etc ...
```

The functions that get called will spawn off threads as needed, so on and so forth.

**UPDATE** - Both were good (pretty much the same) answers.  I accepted the one with the lower rep to share the wealth.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way to do this. It's a bit clumsy (to have to write five long lines of code just to be able to call a method) but that's Java :(

Comment: haha, after about a year of php, working on this project in java is an absolute delight!  a real language api is something i took for granted.

Comment: You don’t write five lines for calling a method. You write five lines for calling a method when a button is pressed. That is a difference.

Comment: I think Aaron's objection was that some languages would just let you pass a function pointer to coolfunction1, rather than having to wrap it with a new object.

Comment: Then why doesn’t he say so? Why do I have to keep guessing what people really mean when they are clearly unable to express themselves? :(

Answer (score 1):

That’s not too bad. I prefer to use [Actions](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) and create [JButtons](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) from them:

```
Action fooAction = new AbstractAction() { ... };
JButton fooButton = new JButton(fooAction);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will keep this in mind should I run into a similar problem

Comment: Yeah, You can reuse action with menus and disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Its one of the correct ways to do it.

You are using anonymous listeners but there is an alternatif

nicely explained on http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

where you write a class that implements ActionListener and have it handle the logic for you

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that code is fine, as Java code goes. It's a good example for Java's often-criticized verbosity - in this case due to the lack of closures.

Comment: I havent used closures because i didnt understand them, but your comment is starting to connect some dots for me, thanks

Comment: Basically, a closure is a standalone method (without a class) that you can pass as parameter to a method - exactly what is needed in your example. The anonymous classes you're using offer the same functionality, just with a lot of boilerplate around very little code.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do something like this:

```
public class ButtonPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton button1, button2, button3;
    public ButtonPanel() {
        button1 = new JButton(this);
        button2 = new JButton(this);
        button3 = new JButton(this):
        ...
    }

    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if( e.getSource() == button1 ) action1();
        else if( e.getSouce() == button2  ) action2();
        else if( e.getSource() == button3 ) action3();
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem I have with this is now actionPerformed is now part of this class's public API, even though no client code can use it directly.  If you insist on using a single ActionListener, it's probably better to create a new, private instance and pass that to your controls.

Comment: It's a question of priorities; whether a clean API or easily read code is more important to your set of constraints.  I don't think my suggestion is something that's good *most of the time* but it is certainly another valid way to do things.  I'm a little disappointed you voted it down.  Ah well.